# How can I create a program who's user interface details & other details can be set differently for differnt users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, themes

I am creating a program for managing an office in asp.net c# that can be run by different users-clients.
 I want each one to be able to set specific details according to individual needs such as texts of headers label texts button color and style etc.

> How can this be done?

Comment: I take it by the tags that this is a website?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You must use 2 thing in your web-app:

1. **Cookie** for saving user select theme and use that for other times [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/cookies_in_c_.aspx).
2. **Theme** Absently you now What I'm talking about(you can see this links: [1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ThemesAndSkins.aspx), [2](http://odetocode.com/articles/423.aspx) ).

> We use cookie (it's alternative way) to save Selected theme in that, and check for this cookie in `session.Start`(or better place) and if exist set that for user.

**More Link:**
[Walkthrough: Creating User-Selectable Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366514.aspx)

Comment: "Absently you now What" what?

Comment: Mean: "such as texts of headers label texts button color and style etc"